# No file fetched with "wget -r"

Tags: wget

I use the following command to recursively download the rpms file from a web server

```
wget -r -np -R "index.html*" http://central-7-0-x86-64.rocksclusters.org/install/rolls/
```

After two minutes, I see

```
Total wall clock time: 2m 41s
Downloaded: 113 files, 1.2M in 4.7s (252 KB/s)
```

However, there are no *.rpm in the folders. It only fetched the folder names and some xml files!

How can I tell `wget` to fetch all files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to either increase recursion maximum depth level with `-l`:

```
wget -r -np -R "index.html*" -l 10 http://central-7-0-x86-64.rocksclusters.org/install/rolls/
```

or replace `-r` with `-m`:

```
wget -m -np -R "index.html*" -l 10 http://central-7-0-x86-64.rocksclusters.org/install/rolls/
```

Comment: Yes, I tried both. You have to be more specific.

Comment: The second worked finally